# CryptoJS decrypts in the backend, but not frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptojs

I have a value that I am encrypting in the backend of my webpage and then sending back to the frontend to be decrypted. This is the code I am using for the backend to encrypt (and decrypt as a test):

```
let message = {"response": CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(data).toString("base64"), result))};
              
let response = message["response"];
let AESdecrypt = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(response.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8), result);
console.log(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(AESdecrypt));
    
res.send(message); // send all data from DB
```

This code works and also decrypts successfully, so I used the same decryption code on the frontend:

```
let responseYes = response.response;
let AESdecrypt = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(responseYes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8), sessionStorage["AESKey"]);
console.log(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(AESdecrypt));
```

When I run this code, the console.log is blank in the frontend. I have no idea how to get this to work as I am using the same exact code from the same library and it just doesn't work. The keys are the same. Is there anyway I can get this to work?

Comment: Just use TLS and skip symmetrically encrypting some data yourself. Without TLS this scheme doesn't provide any security because the key has to be sent over the wire at some point.

Comment: I’m just trying to get an answer, does it matter? I’m using RSA anyway to send the keys, and the whole system behind this is irrelevant. I was simply asking how I would fix this.

Comment: If it works in the backend but not in the frontend and both use the _same_ code, then most likely the data (or its encoding) is different. Therefore you should compare the data (ciphertext and passphrase).